# Can jQuery retrieve a file?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, file

I have a django application that creates xls and txt files.

I'm trying to create a button which sends a **jQuery.get** request to django, django then returns a freshly created file to jQuery which in turn pops open a **save as** dialog.

My code looks like this:

```
jQuery("#testButton").live("click",function()
{
    jQuery.jGrowl("click");
    jQuery.get("/filetest",function(data){});

});


<div id="testButton" class="button">CLICK TO TEST</div>
```

Getting the file to jQuery is easy, but I have no idea how to then raise a **Save As** dialog.

Any assistance would be fantastic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use iframe in your page and change with jquery the  source, to the file you want to  download.

this code put in html body :

```
<iframe id="download" style="width:0px;height:0px;display:none;"></iframe>
```

and the jquery in event of click look like:

```
$('#download').attr("src",location.href+"&make_excell=1");
```

in your sever side send the file back when the request **`make_excell`**  with a content-type

Comment: i found another way via plugin
http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_plugin_for_requesting_ajax_like_file_downloads/

Answer (score 0):

How about a `window.open` invocation which opens a server-side file that sends a Content-Type of a file attachment along with the file contents in the Content Body?